# How to install an application from gitweb

Tags: 12.04, install-from-source, arm

I need to get the latest available version of an application called **arm** which is a terminal monitor for Tor.

The download instructions [on the application webpage][2] has a link to an older version that I can get [through a package in Ubuntu](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/tor-arm). The latest version is available in the  [gitweb](https://gitweb.torproject.org/arm.git/tree). I downloaded it by using **snapshot** and then tried to build it on Ubuntu 12.04 from its source by using (./configure && make && make install). I got an error that says bash: ./configure: No such file  or director

Any idea how can I install the application from gitweb or how to get the latest version of the application that I want.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to be in the same folder as the configure script.

Comment: Maybe run setup.py?

Comment: Thanks for your solutions but none of them works for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no *configure* script in this program. Do that:

1. cd into the directory of this application
2. `chmod +x ./install`
3. `./install`

The install program will invoke the setup.py script appropriately.
This assumes you already have all the dependencies necessary to build the program.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I`m still not able to get it installed when I tried what you just mentioned I got this error: `"python: can't open file 'src/prereq.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory." indeed, there is no folder or file that has that name in the folder that I got from gitweb! Here is the download instruction in the application webpage https://www.atagar.com/arm/download.php

Comment: From the website you pointed out, download the [tarball](https://www.atagar.com/arm/resources/static/arm-1.4.5.0.tar.bz2). There exists a `src` folder.